# Read a formatted text file via python

Tags: python

I want to read a txt file, I need to read only that specific information of file which has my dataFields and dataValues ( ID through Comments) and ignore rest of the file.
can anyone assist me to read the file and put it in the list something like below:

```
data_list = [
    ['ID', '000'], 
    ['Number', '4814771'], 
    ['Code', '001'], 
    ['Branch', '00000'], 
    ['Source', 'General Ledger'], 
    ['Comments', '']
]
```

it is huge file the file format is as below:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        000
Number:                    48889
Code:                      001
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document1
Comments:
Line15
************************************************
line17
line18
line19
line20
line21
line22
line23
line24
line25
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        001
Number:                    48890
Code:                      002
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document2
Comments:
line33
************************************************
line35
line36
line37
line38
line39
line40
line41
line42
line43
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        002
Number:                    48891
Code:                      003
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document2
Comments:
line51
************************************************
```

I had the code to read the data information of the file but I need support to read more than one block of data information in the file and ignore those extra lines in the file.

```
# Open the file in read mode
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create an empty list to store the lines
    lines = []

    # Iterate over the lines of the file
    for line in file:
        # Remove the newline character at the end of the line
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(':') 
        line = [x.strip(' ') for x in line]

        # Append the line to the list
        lines.append(line)

# Print the list of lines
print(lines)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Add `if` statements to check if the line meets your criteria. For instance, if the line begins with `ID:` you can start a new list of fields. When you get to `Comments:` you can append the list of fields to the result list.

Comment: Please make an honest attempt to solve the problem yourself. Then we'll help you fix it if necessary. We won't write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar  I am new to the python programming language and yeah that is the I am asking for more support.

Comment: We're not a tutoring service. If you're a beginner you need to learn the language elsewhere.

Comment: look for your landmark row then start a new record using `next(file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I think I would approach this by reading rows until the landmark

```
"- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -"
```

This signals the beginning of a new record for which the following six lines constitute data. I would pick those 6 lines out via `next()`. I'll also use `io.StringIO()` rather than `open()` just to make it easier to test without me having to create a file.

**So, Given:**

```py
data = """
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        000
Number:                    48889
Code:                      001
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document1
Comments:
Line15
************************************************
line17
line18
line19
line20
line21
line22
line23
line24
line25
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        001
Number:                    48890
Code:                      002
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document2
Comments:
line33
************************************************
line35
line36
line37
line38
line39
line40
line41
line42
line43
- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -
ID:                        002
Number:                    48891
Code:                      003
Branch:                    06789
Source:                    Document2
Comments:
line51
************************************************
""".strip()
```

We can generate a list of dictionaries (which I personally feel is a better option) via:

```py
import io

landmark = "- - - - - - data Information - - - - - - -"

results = []
with io.StringIO(data) as file_in:
    for row in file_in:
        if row.strip() != landmark:
            continue

        results.append(dict([
            tuple(map(str.strip, x.split(":", 1)))
            for x
            in [next(file_in) for _ in range(6)]
        ]))
print(results)
```

giving you:

```
[
    {'ID': '000', 'Number': '48889', 'Code': '001', 'Branch': '06789', 'Source': 'Document1', 'Comments': ''},
    {'ID': '001', 'Number': '48890', 'Code': '002', 'Branch': '06789', 'Source': 'Document2', 'Comments': ''},
    {'ID': '002', 'Number': '48891', 'Code': '003', 'Branch': '06789', 'Source': 'Document2', 'Comments': ''}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is formatted as follows, I think this is what you are looking for.

Input:

```
data Information - - - - - - - 
ID: 000 
Number: 48889 
Code: 001 
Branch: 06789 
Source: Document1 
Comments: This is a comment
data Information - - - - - - - 
ID: 0001
Number: 48889 
Code: 001 
Branch: 06789 
Source: Document1 
Comments: Another Comment
```

```py
data_list = []

# Open the file in read mode
with open('./myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create a dictionary to store related information for a single entry
    data_item = {}

    # Iterate over the lines of the file
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        # Skip the "data Information - -" line
        if i % 7 == 0:
            continue

        # Remove the newline character at the end of the line
        line = line.strip()

        # Split the line into key-value pairs
        key, value = map(str.strip, line.split(':'))

        # Store the key-value pair in the data_item dictionary
        data_item[key] = value

        # If a group of 7 lines has been processed, add the data_item to the data_list
        if i % 7 == 6:
            data_list.append(data_item)
            data_item = {}

# Print the data
print(data_list)
```

I decided to use a list instead of a list of list. An object could also be used.

Comment: This falsely assumes that the data repeats every 7 lines. And every line can be split into 2 items by ":".

Comment: *"Assuming the file is formatted as follows"* Why? OP already showed their format.

Comment: @gre_gor It wasn't originally formatted like that. "esqew" edited it to format the file like that. It then made me uncertain as to whether or not it was actually formatted like that.

Comment: esqew only added tabs, so it's shown properly. And you answered half an hour after that.